# Jetpack compose popup menu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-dropdownmenu

I am trying to rewrite my project UI using Jetpack compose. Any idea to add popup menu using jetpack compose in android?. like this one below.

[image: like this one]

I tried to implement it using Stack() layout but the results are not up to the mark.

```
@Composable
fun LiveDataComponentList(productList: List<Product>) {
    AdapterList(data = productList) { product ->
        Stack() {
            Clickable(onClick = { PopupState.toggleOwner(product) }) {
                Card(...) {...}

            if (PopupState.owner == product) {
                Surface(color = Color.Gray,modifier = Modifier.gravity(Alignment.TopEnd) + Modifier.padding(12.dp)) {
                    Column() {
                        Text("menu 1")
                        Text("menu 2")
                        Text("menu 3")
                        Text("menu 4")
                        Text("menu 5")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and PopupState is

```
@Model
object PopupState
{
    var owner:Product?=null
    fun toggleOwner(item:Product)
    {
        if(owner==item)
            owner=null
        else
            owner=item
    }
}
```

result is

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ0cJ.png)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the [**`DropdownMenu`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#dropdownmenu).

Something like:

```
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

DropdownMenu(
    expanded = expanded,
    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
) {
    DropdownMenuItem(
        text = {  Text("Refresh") },
        onClick = { /* Handle refresh! */ }
    )
    DropdownMenuItem(
        text = { Text("Settings") },
        onClick = { /* Handle settings! */ }
    )
    Divider()
    DropdownMenuItem(
        text = { Text("Send Feedback") },
        onClick = { /* Handle send feedback! */ }
    )
}
```

It works with M3. With M2 you have to use:

```
androidx.compose.material.DropdownMenuItem(
    onClick = { expanded = false }
) {
    Text("All Accounts")
}
```

[image]

About the position, as explained in the documentation:

> A `DropdownMenu` behaves similarly to a `Popup`, and will use the position of the parent layout to position itself on screen. **Commonly a `DropdownMenu` will be placed in a **`Box`** with a sibling that will be used as the 'anchor'**.

Example:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)
){
    IconButton(onClick = { expanded = true }) {
        Icon(
            Icons.Default.MoreVert,
            contentDescription = "Localized description"
        )
    }
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
    ) {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: How to set it's position around a button or any other view?

Comment: @TalhaAkbar Check the updated answer. It uses the position of the parent layout to position itself on screen.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I'm not seeing the part where you position the menu based on the position of the parent layout

Comment: @MKiperszmid *Commonly a `DropdownMenu` will be placed in a `Box` with a sibling that will be used as the 'anchor'.* In the example the `DropdownMenu` uses the `IconButton` as *'anchor'*

Answer (score 12):

Since DropDownPopup was removed, I implemented one using [DropDownMenu](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/material/dropdownmenu/) instead like this:

PopupMenu:

```
@Composable
fun PopupMenu(
    menuItems: List<String>,
    onClickCallbacks: List<() -> Unit>,
    showMenu: Boolean,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    toggle: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    DropdownMenu(
        toggle = toggle,
        expanded = showMenu,
        onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() },
    ) {
        menuItems.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                onDismiss()
                onClickCallbacks[index]
            }) {
                Text(text = item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Toggle (thing to long click on to trigger PopupMenu):

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Toggle() {
    var showMenu by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    PopupMenu(
        menuItems = listOf("Delete"),
        onClickCallbacks = listOf { println("Deleted") },
        showMenu = showMenu,
        onDismiss = { showMenu = false }) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {}, onLongClick = {
                showMenu = true
            }),
            text = "Long click here",
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Is It possible to add anything other than just a Text()? Crashes when adding an ImageView for example..

Comment: How can this be attached to a button?

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found a solution to this, the key component is **DropdownPopup**

```
@Composable
fun LiveDataComponentList(productList: List<Product>) {
    AdapterList(data = productList) { product ->


        Clickable(onClick = { PopupState.toggleOwner(product) }) {
            Card(...) {...}
        }
        if (PopupState.owner == product) {
            DropdownPopup(dropDownAlignment = DropDownAlignment.End)
            {

                Surface(
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                    elevation = 16.dp,
                    color = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier.gravity(Alignment.End)+ Modifier.padding(end = 10.dp)
                )
                {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {

                        MenuItem(text ="Edit", onClick = {})
                        MenuItem(text = "Delete", onClick = {})
                        MenuItem(text = "Details", onClick = {})


                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
}

@Composable
fun MenuItem(text: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Clickable(onClick = onClick, modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp)) {
        Text(text = text, style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1)

    }
}
```

This solution works fine with compose version **dev10**

Comment: DropDownPopup was removed on:

August 5, 2020

androidx.compose.ui:ui-*:0.1.0-dev16 

Removed dropdownPopup. (I00430)

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#0.1.0-dev16

Comment: removed and replaced by?

Comment: @Jonathan perhaps replaced by `DropdownMenu`

Comment: How can we set alignment with `DropdownMenu`?

Answer (score 1):

For My use case I created a Icon button which has pop up menu and that can be used where pop menu is needed.

```
@Composable
fun PopUpMenuButton(
    options: List<PopUpMenuItem>,
    action: (String) -> Unit,
    iconTint: Color = Color.Black,
    modifier: Modifier
) {

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column {

        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)) {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                expanded = !expanded
            }) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_dots),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
                    tint = iconTint
                )
            }
        }

        Box(modifier = modifier) {
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .widthIn(min = 120.dp, max = 240.dp)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
            ) {
                options.forEachIndexed { _, item ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        expanded = false
                        action(item.id)
                    }) {
                        Row(
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                painterResource(id = item.icon),
                                contentDescription = null,
                                tint = iconTint,
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                            Text(
                                text = item.label,
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    if (item.hasBottomDivider) {
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then I created a simple data class for defining menu item

```
data class PopUpMenuItem(
    val id: String,
    val label: String,
    val icon: Int,
    val hasBottomDivider: Boolean = false,
)
```

Then at the calling side I simply use this button like this

```
        PopUpMenuButton(
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
            options = PopMenuOptionsProvider.sectionCardMenu,
            iconTint = MaterialTheme.extendedColor.regularGray,
            action = { menuId -> onSectionMenuAction(menuId) }
        )
```

It can be further refactored to make it more extensible, but this worked for me.

Comment: Having trouble getting this code to compile.  `DropdownMenuItem()` needs another parameter (probably added since your code was written).  Could you list the imports you used?